# PIL Image.Open causes RecursionError

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I wrote a program and as in one part of it, im showing as an output a series of images that you can move between with next/prev buttons
each time next/prev is being clicked, click_dict is being updated with the correct route to the next image, and than I run this code:

```
        def set_image():
            wordvar.set("Word: "+str(click_dict['curr_word']))
            word_found_var.set("Word Count: " + str(click_dict['cnt_appearances']))
            tot_word_found_var.set("Total Found Count: 
                        "+str(click_dict['curr_index']+1)+"/"+str(click_dict['tot_cnt_appearances']))
            filelbl_var.set("File: " + click_dict['curr_file'] + " Page: " + 
                        str(int(click_dict['curr_page'])+1))
            im = Image.open(click_dict['curr_directory'] + "//" + click_dict['curr_filename'])
            zoom = 0.9
            while im.size[0] >= 700:
                x = im.size[0]
                y = im.size[1]
                im = im.resize((round(x * 0.98), round(y * 0.98)))
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
            im.close()
            image.config(image=photo)
            output_window.mainloop()
```

everything works out perfectly and it is moving between the images and updates the StringVars, but eventually after moving between 80-100 pictures, I run into this error:

```
  File "C:/Users/dor27/Desktop/Webber/tryy (1).py", line 46, in set_image
    im = Image.open(click_dict['curr_directory'] + "//" + click_dict['curr_filename'])
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2916, in open
    im = _open_core(fp, filename, prefix)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2897, in _open_core
    result = not accept or accept(prefix)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py", line 50, in _dib_accept
    return i32(prefix[:4]) in [12, 40, 64, 108, 124]
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\_binary.py", line 57, in i32le
    return unpack_from("<I", c, o)[0]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
Python runtime state: initialized
```

I am trying to use im.close() as you can see in the code, but it still doesnt help and eventually everything crashes
any ideas that can prevent this from happening?
thank you!

Comment: Is the path valid? Instead of hard coding it try to assign a variable to the path and pass that onto `Image.open()`

Comment: yeah the path is valid and all images are opened currectly. the only problem is that after I move between the images (even moving back and forth between 2 images who work perfectly fine), eventually I run into this recursion error.

Comment: You reassign the name `im` in the while loop, so what is it that you close? I would think python should garbage collect any object without a reference but I don't know how Pillow handles opened images...